how to change the order of inputs in this extension app to make the newest lead at the top instead of the bottom
As you can see if u tried the code and save an input in the app it will be save in a top to bottom order and i want it to be from bottom to top order, here is the whole code and if you want the html and css code I will give it to you
let myLeads = []
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn")
const leadsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("myLeads") )
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn")

if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
    myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage
    render(myLeads)
}

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){    
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        myLeads.push(tabs[0].url)
        localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) )
        render(myLeads)
    }) 
})

function render(leads) {
    let listItems = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
        listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a>
            </li>
        `
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    localStorage.clear()
    myLeads = []
    render(myLeads)
})

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) )
    render(myLeads)
})

i tried to reverse the order in the render function but it didnt work as expected.

Style the <ul> as a reverse column flexbox with JavaScript:
document.querySelector("ul").style.cssText += 
"display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse";

OR with CSS:
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

localStorage doesn't function on this site so if you want to see a functioning demo see this PLUNKER.


let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) || [];
const ui = document.forms.ui;
const io = ui.elements;
const list = document.getElementById('list');

const render = (array) => {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  array.forEach((url) => {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.textContent = url;
    link.target = '_blank';
    item.append(link);
    frag.append(item);
  });
  list.replaceChildren();
  list.append(frag);
};

ui.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.id === 'del') {
    list.replaceChildren();
    localStorage.clear();
    data = [];
  } else if (e.target.id === 'add') {
    data.push(io.input.value);
    render(data);
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

let test = () => {
  let testData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(testData));
  data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  render(data);
};

render(data);
// test();
// Solution
list.style.cssText += "display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse";
<form id="ui">
  <input id="input">
  <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <button id="del" type="button">Delete All</button>
</form>




thanks the problem is solved by reversing the column of the flex-direction

@MoFahd Note that this is not the answer to your question as it saves nothing in the way you asked for. This is just a trick that makes you see what's saved in reverse order... It's like you saying to me "I need the thing on the right side", then I make you look at some reflex and you say "oh, now the thing is in the right side". The thing is still in the left side. It's just a visual trick to make you think the thing is in the right side... The CSS is not saving the data with the newest entry first... It's just showing the last elements first.

You just need to change .push() with .unshift().
Here's partially working (localStorage is disabled in the snippet so I commented it alongside the extension context feature):


let myLeads = []
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn")
const leadsFromLocalStorage = []; //JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("myLeads") )
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn")

if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
    myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage
    render(myLeads)
}

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){    
    //chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        // EDIT:
        myLeads.unshift(tabs[0].url)
        // localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) )
        render(myLeads)
    //}) 
})

function render(leads) {
    let listItems = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
        listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a>
            </li>
        `
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    // localStorage.clear()
    myLeads = []
    render(myLeads)
})

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // EDIT:
    myLeads.unshift(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    // localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) )
    render(myLeads)
})
<input type="text" id="input-el">
<button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
<button id="tab-btn">SAVE TAB</button>
<button id="delete-btn">DELETE ALL</button>
<ul id="ul-el"></ul>



